# Angular component detail level

Tags: angular, module, components

I am taking over a project at the moment. It is an Angular2 project. In this project, everything is broken down to components at a very detailed level.

For example, there is no header component, instead, there is a module-view component(textModule, ImageModule, buttonModule are all the instance of the module-view component) and header is made of textModule and ImageModule two parts.

I understand the importance of using modular component. But is it nesessary to break the header down into this very trivial level of components?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the functionality for the header in the application this may be a bit of overkill imho. It is important to think about components as being as reusable as possible so that they can be recycled in different parts of the application or future applications. With that in mind, I have a few questions:

1. What version of angular is the project using? You have tagged angularjs and angular2. Angularjs now refers to angular 1.x and Angular refers to angular 2.X, 3.x, 4.x and so on. See [here](http://angularjs.blogspot.ca/2016/10/versioning-and-releasing-angular.html) for a full explanation on semantic versioning in Angular.
2. Are the textModule, imageModule, and buttonModule actual modules or are they components?

Generally speaking, modules are to separate the application into specific concerns - each with their own services, providers, and components - and to provide lazy loading functionality. So having modules for each of these primitive components doesn't make a lot of sense.

I have written applications that have a Header component that is made up of a number of different components. For example you might have a search-bar that is a separate component with its own contained functionality like making calls to a server. You could also have a user-profile component that has a toggled list of options related to the user like logout, see profile etc.

The concept of smart and presentational components is another factor to consider when deciding how to chunk up your application. This [post](http://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-smart-components-vs-presentation-components-whats-the-difference-when-to-use-each-and-why/) describes some best practices in Angular for creating these components.

Hope that helps! Feel free to expand on your question :)